# Spacemacs powerline separator change not working

Tags: spacemacs

I am trying to customize the powerline separator style for Spacemacs. I added the following code to my `.spacemacs` file, as section `11.1.5.5` of the [docs](http://spacemacs.org/doc/DOCUMENTATION.html#orgheadline76) say to do.

```
(setq powerline-default-separator 'bar)
```

However, nothing is changing in my UI. I tried reloading via `SPC f e R` and restarting Spacemacs. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using the stable release (master branch), then you also need to add a call to `(spaceline-compile)` at the end of `dotspacemacs/user-config`.

This is fixed in the develop branch (Spacemacs calls `(spaceline-compile)` at the end of the loading process), so the fix should be included in the next major version (current version is 0.105.20).